# How to refactor this code? I have 3 tags that need to be reselected inside of a list

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

```
for (var i=0; i<vm.tags.length; i++) {
    if (selectedTags[0]) {
        if (vm.tags[i].term_id === selectedTags[0].term_id) {
            vm.tags[i].border1 = true;
        }
    }

    if (selectedTags[1]) {
        if (vm.tags[i].term_id === selectedTags[1].term_id) {
            vm.tags[i].border2 = true;
        }
    }

    if (selectedTags[2]) {
        if (vm.tags[i].term_id === selectedTags[2].term_id) {
            vm.tags[i].border3 = true;
        }
    }
}
```

`vm.tags` is the full list, up to 20+ tags. `selectedTags` is an Array that contains up to 3 tags, basically 3 tags that may contain the same ids as tags inside of `vm.tags`.

If tags inside of `vm.tags` match tags from `selectedTag` I need to change the border value on those `vm.tags`.

Is there a better way to accomplish this than above? Where I have repeating code.

---

`selectedTags` Array example:

`[object, object, object]`

Object example in Array:

```
{
    selected: true,
    term: "term_name",
    term_id: 2349506
}
```

Comment: Could you attached selectedTags array example?

Comment: @Przemek just added!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this:

```
for (var i=0; i<vm.tags.length; i++) {
  for(var j=0; j<selectedTags.length; j++){
    if(selectedTags[j].term_id === vm.tags[i].term_id ){
      var name = 'border'+ ( j + 1 );  
      vm.tags[i][name] = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: They use different `border…` properties in the original code

Comment: I think this is the best solution so far, however I needed to change `vm.tags[i][name]` removed the ., also added `j++` before `var name` because there is no `border0`it starts at `border` do you want to update?

Answer (score 0):

If you can change up the way you use `border1`, `border2`, and `border3` into an array, then this can be accomplished by looping over the `vm.tags` and for each there looping over `selectedTags` and comparing the IDs. When you have a match, you can push the value of the `selectedTags` iterator into a `borders` array. This would look something like:

```
for (var i=0; i<vm.tags.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j<selectedTags.length; j++) {
            if(selectedTags[j].term_id === vm.tags[i]) {
            // make sure the array exists before pushing to it
            vm.tags[i].borders = vm.tags[i].borders || [];
            vm.tags[i].borders.push(j);
        }
    };
};
```

This of course depends on whether or not you can refactor your use of `border1`, `border2` and `border3` into an array that could have any combination of `[0, 1, 2]`.

I suggest this because using numbered values in a data structure like that can get unwieldy quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that uses javascript array map and filter functions to accomplish the same, probably less readable but it is another option:

```
var addBorders = vm.tags.map(function(obj, k) {
  if (selectedTags.filter(function(o) { return o.term_id === obj.term_id; }).length)
    obj['border' + (k + 1)] = true;

  return obj;
});
```

Comment: Hmm I just tried this, but slightly buggy, when I remove the borders, thanks for trying tho!